# array of images - upload with afnetworking

Tags: image

I need uplaod image to server like below format

```
"Images:{ {image:IMAGE,caption:’CAPTION’}, {image:IMAGE,caption:’CAPTION’}, {image:IMAGE,caption:’CAPTION’} } "
```

with afnetworking. How it can be done?